# How to use Wordpress to embed a SoundCloud download link?

Tags: advanced-custom-fields, api, embed

I'm trying to embed a download link for previews in a music site I'm building for a couple of friends. They are currently filling up the system with content and I'm using a SoundCloud iframe HTML5 code and secret link in a custom field to insert into the track's page:

http://www.instrumentalbackgroundmusic.com/royalty-free-music/stutter-glitch-orchestral/

The 'download' link isn't appearing despite it being enabled in SoundCloud and visible on the SoundCloud page for the track:

https://soundcloud.com/instrumentalbgm/stutter-glitch-orchestral

Is there any way I can 'force' the download link to appear? I can't see anything in the SC API about modifying the HTML5 embed code to show the download button...

Here's my current code for the embed using Advanced Custom fields:

```
<?php // Soundcloud preview
if(get_field('sc_preview')) :
echo '<div class="tempsc">' . get_field('sc_preview') . '</div>';
endif; ?>
```

And there's some embed code as an example:

```
<iframe width="100%" height="166" scrolling="no" frameborder="no" src="https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=https%3A//api.soundcloud.com/tracks/110094906"></iframe>
```

How do I embed the SoundCloud html5 widget and get the 'download' link to work in the widget? If it involves appending something to the URL of the track, is there a Wordpress function I can use to regex the embed code and add this info?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you may have already found out, presently, soundcloud do not allow modification of parameters with the HTML5 widget and only when using the flash player. See here for more info: 
http://help.soundcloud.com/customer/portal/articles/241151-can-i-change-parameters-on-embedded-players-

The options for the flash player can be found here:
https://github.com/soundcloud/Widget-JS-API/wiki/widget-options

I hope this answers your question anyway.

Comment: Thanks TomC, appreciate the info. This question was probably better suited for Stackexchange, so I expect it to be closed shortly, but I'll look into those links in the meantime.

Comment: and anyone else interested, I managed to actually get the download link to appear using parameters in the iframe URL: `<iframe width="100%" height="166" scrolling="no" frameborder="no" src="https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=https%3A//api.soundcloud.com/tracks/110089704&buying=false&download=true&sharing=false"></iframe>` - apparently, you have to disable 'buy' in order to see the download link. Again, this isn't a WP-specific thing, so probably best filed in Stackoverflow rather than here as Chip Bennet mentioned.